# Must an ultrafilter orthogonal to all ultrafilters containing an element $a$ contains $a^\perp$?

Tags: lattice-theory, ultrafilters

Let $L$ be an orthocomplemented lattice. We may consider the collection $U$ of ultrafilters on $L$. We say two elements $a, b \in L$ are orthogonal to each other, written as $a \perp b$, if $a \leq b^\perp$ or equivalently $b \leq a^\perp$. And we say two ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V} \in U$ are orthogonal to each other, written as $\mathcal{U} \perp \mathcal{V}$, if there exists $a \in \mathcal{U}$ and $b \in \mathcal{V}$ s.t. $a \perp b$. For each $a \in L$, let $U(a)$ be the collection of all ultrafilters containing $a$.

1. Suppose $\mathcal{U} \perp \mathcal{V}$ for all $\mathcal{V} \in U(a)$, does it follow that $\mathcal{U} \in U(a^\perp)$?
2. If the above does not hold for all orthocomplemented lattice, are there some natural conditions on $L$ that imply this condition? For example, does it hold for all orthomodular lattices?
3. If 1 does not hold, then does the following weaker condition holds: For each collection $A$ of ultrafilters, let $A^\perp = \{\mathcal{U} \in U: \mathcal{U} \perp \mathcal{V}, \forall \mathcal{V} \in A\}$. Then is it true that $(U(a)^\perp)^\perp = (U(b)^\perp)^\perp$ iff $U(a) = U(b)$? Again, if this does not hold in general, are there some natural conditions on $L$ that imply this condition? For example, does it hold for all orthomodular lattices?

Comment: I found a relatively complicated proof of this for orthomodular lattices, which is the case I mostly care about. I’ll leave this question open to see if there’s a simpler proof or a proof for more general orthocomplemented lattices.